# Python, Importlib. Imitation of "from module import * "

Tags: python, module, package, python-importlib

How to imitate `from module import *` with importlib. I know that you can do:

```
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader
module = SourceFileLoader('module.py', os.path.join(CWD,'module.py')).load_module()

module.executeFunction()
```

Is there any way to import module so that we can do `executeFunction()` without writing module.executeFunction()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see this as a good idea, keeping things in objects is definitely the better way to go, but if you so needed to...

```
for func in [func for func in module.__dict__ if not func.startswith("_")]:
    vars()[func] = module.__dict__[func]
```

Leaving out the functions that start with _ is probably a good idea because of builtins, but you can exclude that if you so wish.